# Remote Desktop Connection works fine but RDP file crashes

Tags: remote-desktop

We don't want to give users remote desktop access to the server so we have published applications on the surver and created RDP files that the users run.

This works great on every user's pc with the exception of one machine. Each time this one  machine runs the RDP file it crashes after about 10 -15 seconds. Here is the error message from the event viewer:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: Application Error
Event Category: None
Event ID:    1000
Date: 07/18/2012
Time: 10:07:26 AM
User: N/A
Computer: (X'D OUT)

Description:

Faulting application mstsc.exe, version 6.1.7600.16722, faulting module 
ntdll.dll, version 5.1.2600.6055, fault address 0x00010ef4.
```

The weird part is... we can run the Remote Desktop Connection from the start menu and it connects to the server just fine.

Has this happened to anybody and what did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by removing an invalid Printer on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error a couple of times with mstsc.exe. I would recommend the following.

- Do a memory test on the computer with the error. ntdll.dll errors can occur when you have a bad stick of RAM or other memory errors occur.
- Ensure the computer is up-to-date - install all recommended system updates
- Try repairing your installation of Windows
- Try to RDP into another server to ensure it's nothing on that particular server that's causing the problem. I know it sounds weird but we had a user who's computer was giving us similar problems because of a remote printing tool known as ScrewDrivers. Un-installing that caused the problem to stop so we knew that was the offending service